# Practical C++ - Am I using seperate files and classes correctly?

Tags: c++

I've completed a program as a learning experience to make sure I've got the concepts down. I found the practice project online and decided to try it out. The program compiles and runs exactly how it should with no problems.

The program is a game called Artillery. You have to fire a cannon at one enemy at a time until you hit him. The player inputs the angle at which to shoot the cannon.

My question is this: Am I using correct coding practices? For instance, if I was on a team of people working on this, would my use of classes and objects be the most efficient?

Also, I would like any input on how to improve my code for this program or any tips for easier ways to write any part of the code. The code is as follows:

distang.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef DISTANG_H
#define DISTANG_H

// Calculates angle and distance of shot
class DistAng
{
public:
    double distAng(double);
private:
    double velocity = 200;
    double gravity = 32.2;
    double shotDistance;
    double timeInAir;
    double pi = 3.1415;
};

#endif
```

game.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

// The main loop for playing the game
class Game
{
public:
    void game();
private:
    int killed = 0;
    int enemyDistance = 0;
    double inAngle;
    char done;
    int shots = 0;
    bool killedEnemy = false;
};

#endif
```

highscore.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef HIGHSCORE_H
#define HIGHSCORE_H

// Reads/saves high score from/to file
class HighScore
{
public:
    void highScore(int);
private:
    int intHighScore;
};

#endif
```

startup.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef STARTUP_H
#define STARTUP_H

// Displays the game introduction
class Startup
{
public:
    void startup();
private:
};

#endif
```

DistAng.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "distang.h"

using namespace std;

// Calculates distance and angle of shot
double DistAng::distAng(double inAngle)
{
    inAngle = (inAngle * pi) / 180; // Converts angle from std::cin into radians

    // A bit of simple physics to calculate the distance of shot
    timeInAir = (2.0 * velocity * sin(inAngle)) / gravity;
    shotDistance = round((velocity * cos(inAngle)) * timeInAir);

    return shotDistance;
}
```

Game.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "game.h"
#include <time.h>
#include "distang.h"
#include "highscore.h"

using namespace std;

// Main game loop
void Game::game()
{
    do
    {
        // RNG to generate enemy distance each round :: least distance can be 200, max distance can be 900 :: and std::cout the enemey distance
        srand(time(0));
        enemyDistance = 200 + (rand() % 900);
        cout << "\nThe enemy is " << enemyDistance << " feet away!\n";

        // Creating a couple class object here
        DistAng calculate;
        HighScore submit;

        // Determines if enemy was killes, resets to false each round
        killedEnemy = false;

        // Loop for user input until enemy is hit or runs out of shots
        do
        {
            cout << "What angle? ";

            // Input check
            while (!(cin >> inAngle))
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
            }

            // Keeps track of shots
            shots++;

            // Hit condition counts kills and displays shots taken
            if (enemyDistance == calculate.distAng(inAngle))
            {
                killed++;
                killedEnemy = true;
                cout << "\nYou hit him!\n";
                cout << "It took you " << shots << " shots.\n";
                break;
            }

            // Allows for shot correction if missed
            else if (enemyDistance < calculate.distAng(inAngle))
                cout << "\nYou over shot by " << calculate.distAng(inAngle) - enemyDistance << endl;

            else if (enemyDistance > calculate.distAng(inAngle))
                cout << "\nYou under shot by " << enemyDistance - calculate.distAng(inAngle) << endl;

        } while (shots != 10);

        // End of round if/else conditions for enemy killed or out of shots
        if (shots == 10 && killedEnemy == false)
        {
            shots = 0;
            cout << "You ran out of cannon balls!\n";
            cout << "You've killed " << killed << " of the enemy.\n";
            submit.highScore(killed); // Record enemies killed for duration of game
            killed = 0;

            // Input/New game check
            do
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                cout << "Play again?(Y/N) ";
                cin >> done;
            } while (done != 'y' && done != 'n');

        }

        else
        {
            shots = 0;
            cout << "You've killed " << killed << " of the enemy.\n";

            // Input/Next round check
            do
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                cout << "I see another one, care to shoot again?(Y/N) ";
                cin >> done;
            } while (done != 'y' && done != 'n');
        }

    } while (done != 'n');
}
```

HighScore.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "highscore.h"

using namespace std;

// Reads/saves high score from/to file
void HighScore::highScore(int score)
{
    ifstream readScoreSheet("HighScore.art");

    // Checks current high score first
    if (readScoreSheet.is_open())
    {
        readScoreSheet >> intHighScore;
        readScoreSheet.close();
    }

    else // Condition for first game played
        cout << "No current high score.\n\n"; 

    // Player did not beat high score
    if (intHighScore > score)
        cout << "The current high score is " << intHighScore << " kills!\n\n";

    // If player beat high score
    else if (intHighScore < score)
    {
        ofstream writeScoreSheet("HighScore.art");

        // Replace old score with new score
        if (writeScoreSheet.is_open())
        {
            cout << "New high score!\n\n";
            writeScoreSheet << score;
            writeScoreSheet.close();
        }

        else cout << "Unable to open file"; // Never happens
    }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "game.h"
#include "startup.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// Main function, obviously
int main()
{
    // Class objects
    Startup run;
    Game begin;


    run.startup(); // Call startup function
    begin.game(); // Call main game loop function

    return 0;
}
```

Startup.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "startup.h"

using namespace std;

// Displays introductory text
void Startup::startup()
{
    cout << "Welcome to Artillery!\n\n";
    cout << "You are in the middle of a war and being charged by thousands of enemies!\n";
    cout << "You have one cannon, which you can shoot at any angle.\n";
    cout << "You only have 10 cannonballs for this target.\n\n";
}
```

Comment: If this is all working code, your question might be better placed at SE Code Review site.

Comment: You're using classes as modules, not as templates for objects. I guess that you always create an object of each class. You could have coded the program in C, with some structs here and there.

Comment: The question is better asked at SE Code Review.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'll head over to SE Code Review site.